# Can I take the values from one scenario and pass it to the Performance Scenario and execute all data-sets paralelly using Karate-Gatling

Tags: karate

I have implemented Karate for Functional Regression API Tests and Karate-Gatling for Performance tests with static data and it works great. Now there is a requirement where in I have to use multiple data set from one earlier scenario and pass this data set to Performance scenarios and then execute all the data-sets parallelly.
My Base scenario which will generate the data will be -

```
Scenario: Get the list of Product ID
     Given url url
     When method GET
     Then status 200
     * def productids = $[*].productID
```

Each request will contain around 5 Product ID's and this will be used again to perform a GET in **Product scenario** as shown below

```
Scenario: Product Scenario
    Given url baseUrl + productids
    When method GET
    Then status 200
```

Now the requirement is to run Performance Tests for **Product Scenario** for all the product ID's obtained from the 1st scenario parallelly.
*i.e.: 10 threads of productID1, 10 threads of productID2, 10 threads of productID3 all of them should be triggered parallelly*

Is this possible to implement via Karate-Gatling ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is something we made possible in 1.1.0, can you please read this carefully: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1622

The docs explain this also, screenshot below: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling#chaining

[image]

Of course your feedback is important, try it and in case there are more improvements required, please also consider contributing code !

Comment: Thanks Peter for the quick response. I will try and accordingly update.

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same requirement, but it doesn't really allow sharing the data between scenarios easily.

The workaround I did was -

1. Create a lightweight spring boot REST+JPA app which runs on localhost and expose POST and GET methods for the data I need.
2. At the end of the 1st scenario, post the data I need into the this app in .silent POST requests.
3. At the start of the 2nd scenario, read the data from the app using GET method (again in .silent mode)